# Can a RSC be updated with a store value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, next.js13

I have this React Server Component which can access the initial values or even dispatch actions to the redux store

the initial value is set to be `10`

```
// store/counterSlice.ts
const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 10,
};

// app/serverComponent.tsx
export default async function ServerComponent() {
  const data = await fetchSomeData();
  store.dispatch(updateTestData(data)); // this works

  const counter = store.getState().counter; // this works - gets the initial value of 10

  console.log('this log is shown in the server');

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.description}>
        {/* shows the initial value of 10 */}
        <p>Current Count: {counter.value}</p>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I know that a Server Component can be rerendered in Nextjs using `router.refresh()`

```
// app/clientComponent.tsx
'use client';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from '@/store';
import { increment } from '@/store/counterSlice';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const count = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.value);
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleIncrementCounter = () => {
    dispatch(increment());
    // this rerenders the server component
    router.refresh();
  };

  return (
    <div id='with-font-container'>
      {/* this value us correctly subscribed and updated to the store changes */}
      <p>Current Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleIncrementCounter}>Increment Count</button>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Both components live in the same page and the increment count successfuly
increments the count in the client, but the server component keeps the
initial value of 10, despite `router.refresh()` successfully rerendering (confirmed by `console.log` in the server)

```
// app/page.tsx
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-black text-3xl'>
      <ClientComponent>
        {/* this error is a known next13 bug https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42292 */}
        {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
        <ServerComponent />
      </ClientComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This means that the RSC won't ever be able to access to the *updated* redux store (or any other global store), right?

this is the [code](https://github.com/esponges/next-13-experimental/commits/main) in case you are curious

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe since the RSC lives on the server, its redux instance is alive server-side and never gets updated by the totally separate redux instance running in an end-user's browser. RSCs are not supposed to / not allowed to `useEffect` nor `useState`. If you had used `useDispatch` from react-redux in your `ServerComponent`, which is the way you're supposed to use Redux rather than importing the store directly like you did there, then the build would have failed because useStore/useDispatch calls useEffect and/or useState.

What I would like to see in another answer is someone demonstrating how to essentially achieve what OP is trying to: fetch some data on the server, then have the RSC rerender when the data source is updated.

In the [RSC docs it mentions the refresh sequence happy path for an RSC would need to be implemented by the framework](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0188-server-components.md#update-refetch-sequence). So there would be Next.js and Remix specific answers to this question. It would be great to see an answer detailing how exactly this is done both in Next.js and Remix.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is server store and client store are not in sync. `route.refresh` is rerendering, shipping the server component and client component to the client. But when you are on the client, when you click on `increment` to update the redux store, that server component was already rendered on the server, it has no access to the client code or client store.

If you set up redux in `pages` directory with the `next-redux-wrapper` package, we have `hydrate` action set in the slice

```
extraReducers: {
    [HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload.value,
      };
    },
```

in `getServerSideProps` we fetch data, populate the store and ship this store to the client and the client creates a new store with the server store data. In this case, we send an already fetched, populated store to the client and the client has access to it.

But in your example, every time you call `store.getState().counter` on the server component, you want to read the data from the client side store which is stored in the Provider  and the only way to access this provider is using `useSelector` hook from the client side